# How to apply style to HTML which is being rendered using raw filter

Tags: html, twig

I am getting HTML back in a response. I am using TWIG, to render that on the page, I use `{{ response | raw}}.` This renders the HTML with its default style. How can I apply my own styles?

Comment: What do you mean with it default style? `raw` just prevents `html` from being escaped in `twig`, what is the content in your database?

Comment: @DarkBee Content which I am getting is HTML tags. 
`<div>
<div class="top_row">
<h1>This is the H1 tag</h1>
</div>
<div class="main_content">
<p>Main content is displayed</p>
</div>
</div>`

So when I use `raw` to render it on a page, it renders but I cannot apply style to a specific `div` or `p` tag